# How to add an unselectedTab icon in codename one?

Tags: java, codenameone

I am currently writing an app with CodenameOne using the GUIBuilder.

Now that I added a Tab, I want to let it have an icon from googles material icons.

The problem is, there is an `Tab.setSelectedIcon (int index, Image icon)` and no `Tab.setIcon (int index, Image icon)` or `Tab.setUnselectedIcon (int index, Image icon)`, so the icon disappears as soon as I change the tab.

How can I add the image in a way that it is displayed although I changed the tab?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out:

Instead of using `Tab.set"Any"Icon (int index, Image icon)` you can use `Tab.setTabTitle (String label, Image icon, int index`

Comment: Normally when we add the tab initially we also pass the icon in as the argument so that is the unselected icon.

Comment: Yes, I know, but as the material icons are created in run- and not in "UIBuilder-time", one cannot use them.
_maybe a nice feature for a future UIBuilder ;)_

Comment: Actually there is an RFE to do this for the new GUI builder, FYI I had the exact same pain earlier in the week and wanted to simplify material design tabs so I added the method: `addTab(String title, char materialIcon, float iconSize, Component component)` it's already in the current release (if you do an update client libs).